What replacement parts fits shimano st-ef51, unknown suntour 48-38-28 crankset and 68mm x 122.5mm spindle
I need to replace my old crankset which is some unknown suntour 48-38-28 crankset for 3x8-speed bike. The original BB is an unknown FSA sqare taper 122.5mm x 68mm. Can't find any model number on the FD, but a Shimano SIS at least. The front shifter is an old shimano st-ef51, which I can't find much about, but if it is the same as 510, then it seems I have some choices:
https://productinfo.shimano.com/pdfs/product/archive/2018-2019_Compatibility_v038_en.pdf
Holding the old crankset next to a tx-801(compatible with m311) it does at least seems to have similar gaps between rings and is listed compatible with the st-ef510.
My question is if the m311 should fit the front shifter/frame on a BBUN-300-d-NL. Or is this just a wild gamble? Lot's of unknowns (old chainline specs??), but how bad can this be? I'm running the tx801 on a 2.5mm too short chainline with no big issues. Other suggestions on how to select parts?

Per the document you linked, FC-M311 on its recommended symmetrical 123mm spindle gives a chainline of 50mm.

Here is some data lifted from Sutherland's that explains the D-NL versus LL thing. D-NL spindles are slightly asymmetrical, just not by enough to matter in most applications, hence the confusion about it. Pairing a crank intended for an asymmetrical spindle with a symmetrical one will make the Q-factor asymmetrical and move the chainline out. LL spindles are symmetrical. But because D-NL only has 1.5mm of asymmetry, it all tends to get glossed over. Where it can come into play are the rare situations where you're at the limit of FD range or frame clearance.
So FC-M311 will give its nominal chainline on the 123mm spindle you have, presuming it's symmetrical. FC-TX801 also uses LL123, it's basically just a lower-end crank that does all the same things. The shifter really doesn't matter here; you presumably have one of the mountain/hybrid/"lifestyle" Shimano FDs that's a match with the ring sizes in question, and it will get the cable pull it needs from any non-road Shimano flatbar triple shifter.

That might explain why my left foot has been rubbing the left crankarm for years. Is A or C the drive side? I'm planning on using a symetric crankset on an asymmetric BB in that case. At least that is what I'm currently doing on another bike with no major issues except I get the impression that the chainrings are a bit too close to the frame?

C is the drive side. To my awareness every asymmetric square taper spindle ever has the longer side on the DS, which probably means there's some kind of byzantine exception somewhere.

That explains both my very minor chainring issue (using the smallest rear cog) and why my left foot is rubbing so much on the crankarm.
